# Remove Extra Space below footer inside wordpress iframe containing myBB

Tags: css, wordpress, iframe, footer, mybb

I'm trying to put a forum onto a page in wordpress. I am using 100% width and height and all is well except for one thing, the wordpress page seems to be way too long and the inline frame part with mybb in it has a long background image below the forum. How would I go about fixing this. I am useing a full page template in wordpress with this for my inline frame:

```
<pre></pre> <iframe src="http://ouyadb.com/mybb/" width="100%" height="100%" display:block />
```

Comment: oh and the page im speaking of is : ouyadb.com/forums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify CSS codes margin-bottoms and to remove the margins, white space.
let me check your css files shortly...

on the file
http://ouyadb.com/wp-content/themes/responsive/style.css

```
#content-full {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

then

```
#wrapper{
   padding: 0 20px 0px 20px;
}
```

Comment: that just removes the white space though, i need to remove the black area inside the frame. is there a way to make the inline frame size dynamically ? that would do it i think

Comment: Hmm, you changed your theme, is that black area still there?
I think you just need to remove css margins for your case